# Field 'writeConcern' is currently not supported using Mongock with AWS Document DB

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb, mongock, writeconcern

I am switching a Spring boot application that currently uses Mongo DB, to AWS Document DB. The application uses Mongock to run some scripts to setup the database when it starts up.

Now, when I disable the Mongock from the app and point it to use the Document DB connection, it starts up fine and gets connected to the Document DB as expected and does the CRUD operations.

As soon as I enable Mongock using the AWS Document DB and start up the application, it throws up errors regarding a field 'writeConcern' not being supported by Document DB. The detailed trace is mentioned below. The logs do suggest that the DocumentDB is connected.

```
2024-02-16 14:18:54.267  INFO 49084 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27018], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
2024-02-16 14:18:54.791  INFO 49084 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
2024-02-16 14:18:55.251  INFO 49084 --- [localhost:27018] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1}] to localhost:27018
2024-02-16 14:18:55.252  INFO 49084 --- [localhost:27018] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27018, type=SHARD_ROUTER, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=13, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=572555100}
2024-02-16 14:18:55.315  INFO 49084 --- [localhost:27018] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2}] to localhost:27018
2024-02-16 14:18:56.058  INFO 49084 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3}] to localhost:27018
2024-02-16 14:18:56.458  INFO 49084 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-02-16 14:18:56.493 ERROR 49084 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionDriver' defined in class path resource [com/github/cloudyrock/mongock/driver/mongodb/springdata/v3/config/SpringDataMongoV3Context.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.api.driver.ConnectionDriver]: Factory method 'connectionDriver' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 303: 'Field 'writeConcern' is currently not supported' on server localhost:27018. The full response is {"code": 303, "errmsg": "Field 'writeConcern' is currently not supported", "ok": 0.0, "errorUUID": "9f98fcb2-118a-4a8b-b735-495c14b92af3"}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:337) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1336) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1325) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.sample.springmongomigration.SpringMongoMigrationApplication.main(SpringMongoMigrationApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.api.driver.ConnectionDriver]: Factory method 'connectionDriver' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 303: 'Field 'writeConcern' is currently not supported' on server localhost:27018. The full response is {"code": 303, "errmsg": "Field 'writeConcern' is currently not supported", "ok": 0.0, "errorUUID": "9f98fcb2-118a-4a8b-b735-495c14b92af3"}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 303: 'Field 'writeConcern' is currently not supported' on server localhost:27018. The full response is {"code": 303, "errmsg": "Field 'writeConcern' is currently not supported", "ok": 0.0, "errorUUID": "9f98fcb2-118a-4a8b-b735-495c14b92af3"}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:175) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:358) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:279) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:100) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:490) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:71) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:253) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:202) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:118) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:110) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWriteCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:371) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWriteCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:362) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:286) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:279) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CreateIndexesOperation$1.call(CreateIndexesOperation.java:197) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CreateIndexesOperation$1.call(CreateIndexesOperation.java:192) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:650) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:612) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CreateIndexesOperation.execute(CreateIndexesOperation.java:192) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CreateIndexesOperation.execute(CreateIndexesOperation.java:72) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:187) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeCreateIndexes(MongoCollectionImpl.java:847) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.createIndexes(MongoCollectionImpl.java:830) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.createIndexes(MongoCollectionImpl.java:825) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.createIndex(MongoCollectionImpl.java:810) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.mongodb.sync.v4.repository.MongoSync4RepositoryBase.createRequiredUniqueIndex(MongoSync4RepositoryBase.java:99) ~[mongodb-sync-v4-driver-4.3.8.jar:na]
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.mongodb.sync.v4.repository.MongoSync4RepositoryBase.ensureIndex(MongoSync4RepositoryBase.java:58) ~[mongodb-sync-v4-driver-4.3.8.jar:na]
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.mongodb.sync.v4.repository.MongoSync4RepositoryBase.initialize(MongoSync4RepositoryBase.java:43) ~[mongodb-sync-v4-driver-4.3.8.jar:na]
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.core.driver.ConnectionDriverBase.initialize(ConnectionDriverBase.java:40) ~[mongock-driver-core-4.3.8.jar:na]
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.mongodb.springdata.v3.config.SpringDataMongoV3Context.connectionDriver(SpringDataMongoV3Context.java:27) ~[mongodb-springdata-v3-driver-4.3.8.jar:na]
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.mongodb.springdata.v3.config.SpringDataMongoV3Context$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$99079470.CGLIB$connectionDriver$0(<generated>) ~[mongodb-springdata-v3-driver-4.3.8.jar:na]
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.mongodb.springdata.v3.config.SpringDataMongoV3Context$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$99079470$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e5fe51b6.invoke(<generated>) ~[mongodb-springdata-v3-driver-4.3.8.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.mongodb.springdata.v3.config.SpringDataMongoV3Context$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$99079470.connectionDriver(<generated>) ~[mongodb-springdata-v3-driver-4.3.8.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

I have reached out to AWS support but they say that this could be an issue with the Mongock driver connecting to Document DB as the logs suggest the connection error using the Mongock driver, whereas the actual mondodb driver connects as expected with the Document DB.

PS: This application with Mongock enabled and when connected to MongoDB, works absolutely fine.

I have already tried a suggestion from AWS support to keep the replicaSet=rs0 in the connection string, but that introduced a totally new error.

`String template = "mongodb://%s:%s@%s/testdb?ssl=true&sslInvalidHostNameAllowed=true&retryWrites=false&replicaSet=rs0";`

This threw a connection error mentioned below.

There is not enough help on the forums regarding this specific issue and configuration. Please let me know if you have faced this before or have any insights about this.

Thanks

````
2024-02-19 10:53:23.832  INFO 73292 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27018], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=REPLICA_SET, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', requiredReplicaSetName='rs0'}
2024-02-19 10:53:23.832  INFO 73292 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server localhost:27018 to client view of cluster
2024-02-19 10:53:24.245  INFO 73292 --- [localhost:27018] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27018

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:143) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    ... 4 common frames omitted

2024-02-19 10:53:24.373  INFO 73292 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : No server chosen by com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@6c977dcf from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=localhost:27018, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
2024-02-19 10:53:54.388  INFO 73292 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-02-19 10:53:54.427 ERROR 73292 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionDriver' defined in class path resource [com/github/cloudyrock/mongock/driver/mongodb/springdata/v3/config/SpringDataMongoV3Context.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.api.driver.ConnectionDriver]: Factory method 'connectionDriver' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@6c977dcf. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=localhost:27018, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]```
````

Comment: The error in the output log is related to server localhost:27018, are you using it with local environment? can you share the related configuration?

Comment: Yes, it says localhost because I am creating a tunnel from my local machine to AWS EC2 through to the DocumentDB. So I open a tunnel on my local using ssh on the cluster at port 27017 and map it to 27018 on my local. Hope that explains. Let me know if you need more details.